# Developer Express, GDI+ shutdown

Tags: delphi, gdi+, devexpress, tms

According to [this article](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A1015.aspx), we have to call `GdiPlusUnload` before unloading dlls. According to [other articles](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B94305.aspx), we also have to call `dxInitializeGDIPlus` and `dxFinalizeGDIPlus`.

We have a lot of dlls, all build with developer express runtime packages.

Do we have to call these procedures in all dlls using devexpress components? Both `dxFinalizeGDIPlus` and `GdiPlusUnload`?

We also use some components from TMS Software. How do they use gdi+? Should we call some initialize/finalize-procedures there too?

Answer (score 3):

I will answer a part of your question related to DevExpress controls.  You should call the dxInitializeGDIPlus / dxFinalizeGDIPlus methods in all DLLs where our controls are used.  There is no need to use the GdiPlusUnload method if you used the aforementioned methods.

Unfortunately, I cannot tell you about the TMS Software controls specific :(.

Comment: and using runtime packages does not change this in any way?
What should happen if we do not call dxInitializeGDIPlus/dxFinalizeGDIPlus?

Comment: Generally, it is difficult to predict the exact effect.  We have received many reports from our customers that an application is not unloaded correctly when the dxFinalizeGDIPlus method is not called.  This is because the gdiplus.dll is not unloaded in this case.

Comment: We tried to move our call to dxInitializeGDIPlus/dxFinalizeGDIPlus back into our dlls. That made the application hang every time.

Comment: Should there be any need of calling GdiPlusShutdown (from windows api) too?